# ¿Cómo funcionan las validaciones en herencia con Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, herencia, spring-security

Necesito validar un objeto que tiene herencia y además múltiple.
Os explico: en mi aplicación web, tengo una superclase llamada Presupuesto con sus parámetros: destinatario, cliente, total. Un poco de lo que va el programa, de hacer presupuestos. De Presupuesto heredan ObraNueva (con superficie y calidad) y Reforma (largo, ancho, alto, modificación) . Y a su vez, de Reforma hay otra relación de herencia con Aseos (sanitarios) y Cocina (metrosmueble, metrosencimera), clases hijas de Reforma que a su vez heredan de Presupuesto.

Cada uno de los objetos ObraNueva, Aseos y Cocina tienen su formulario. Y después se válida el Presupuesto con los datos finales.

¿Cómo funcionarían las validaciones en este caso? Ando bastante perdido cuando hay herencia. Imagino que es igual que sin relación de herencia, aunque lo desconozco.